# revision entry is the same with saveEntry in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, entries

I have made a plugin where I save a status of a related entry. I have enabled revisions in the section. But when I update the status entry, a new version is made with the newest content, but all the content of the previous versions are overwritten and are the same as the latest version.

Did I forgot something?

My code:

```
$saveStatus = craft()->elements->getElementById($statusEntry->id);
$saveStatus->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
                            'eigenaarId'  => array($user->id),
                            'advertentieId' => array($entryID),
                            'doorkoppelaarId' => array($doorkoppelaar->id),
                            'statusCode' => $status['status_code'],
                            'statusMessage' => $return[$i]['message'],
                            'statusErrors' => json_encode($errors),
                            'statusWarnings' => json_encode($warnings),
                        ));

$newStatusEntry = craft()->entries->saveEntry($saveStatus);
```

[image]

Comment: You're saying a new row isn't being created in the `craft_entryrevisions` table for that entryId, but is's overwriting an existing row?

Comment: No, the new entry is created. But all the other revisions are overwrited with the latest data.

Comment: Hrm... can you take a before/after screenshot of the `craft_entryrevisions` table filtered by the entryId you're editing?

Comment: I have uploaded the image in the start post.